# Power BI embeded - Create profile return FeatureNotAvailableError

Tags: azure, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

I am trying to use power bi embeded according to the following instructions https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/developer/embedded/embed-multi-tenancy#create-a-profile as a multitenant. But I am stuck on the CreateProfile step, which returns the following response:
`{ "error": { "code": "FeatureNotAvailableError", "pbi.error": { "code": "FeatureNotAvailableError", "parameters": {}, "details": [] } } }`

But if I call GET, everything works as it should. I really followed the instructions exactly. Setting up the app, setting up tenant.

What could be causing this error? Thank you

I tried googling for a solution, calling the api differently, setting it up in Power BI, but nothing helped. I want to achieve the API call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error might occur if you missed **enabling creating profiles** option for the service principal in **`Tenant Settings`** of Power Bi Admin Portal.

I registered one Azure AD application and added it to group as below:

[image]

Initially, I generated **access token** using client credentials flow via Postman without enabling creating profiles option in Tenant settings of Power Bi:

```http
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/tenantId/oauth2/v2.0/token
grant_type:client_credentials
client_id: appId
client_secret: secret 
scope: https://analysis.windows.net/powerbi/api/.default
```

**Response:**

[image]

When I used this token to create profile, I too got **same error** as below:

```json
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/profiles
Authorization: Bearer <token>
{
    "displayName": "SriProfile"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

To **resolve** the error, make sure to **enable creating profiles** option in the `Tenant settings` of Power Bi Admin Portal by adding **group** with service principal like below:

[image]

Now, generate the **bearer token** again after few minutes and use it to run the **`POST`** request where **profile** will be created successfully as below:

```json
POST https://api.powerbi.com/v1.0/myorg/profiles
Authorization: Bearer <token>
{
    "displayName": "SriProfile"
}
```

**Response:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much. I messed with the settings and set up something else.